# Printing in color from printf(9)

Tags: colors, console, freebsd

Is it possible to print to console in color from the kernel's version of printf?  Can I see the same escape codes that I can in userland?  Does the kernel understand the console well enough to be able to provide termcap style APIs and constants for specific color?  If so, which header are they defined in?

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly print arbitrary escape sequences from kernel. It would happily put whatever bytes out on a terminal. Whether those bytes would be interpreted as color, kernel, generally speaking, has no idea.

So, it is possible to print and you can see the same escape codes once you read kernel messages (i.e. if kernel prints XTERM-style colors and you happen to look at them via serial port with a terminal program that either uses XTERM or emulates XTERM escape sequences itself)

As for whether kernel knows much about your terminal type and able to use termcap info, the answer is, in general, no.

In userland terminal type is a matter of convention. Login script tries to figure out what kind of terminal you may be connected to and then sets TERM to appropriate type in the shell's environment. Forked processes inherit it and use the type in order to figure out how to do certain things on specific terminal. Usually it involves some sort of curses library.

Kernel, on the other hand is fairly minimalistic beast that does not really give much of a damn what's on the other end of whatever happens to be its console -- serial port, firewire or video card. For all practical purposes, console may not even be connected to anything at all.

Practically, you will need to solve two problems:

- Have a way to configure terminal type for particular TTY device you want to use.
- Provide kernel with som sort of termcap/terminfo data for that terminal type and an API to produce appropriate escape sequences for output on specific TTY. In other words -- in-kernel curses library.